# Create logical vector of given positions for "TRUE"

Tags: r

I would like to create a logical vector of given size (let's say 6) with the "TRUE" indexes that are given by another vector:
`a=c(1,4)`
Desired output:

```
T,F,F,T,F,F
```

Thanks for tips.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a logical vector and then assign the values you want.

```
x <- logical(6)    # All FALSE
a <- c(1, 4)
x[a] <- TRUE

x
#[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

Comment: Also `replace(rep(F, 6), a, T)`

Comment: Assuming you define `a <- c(1,4)` as in the question prompt, you can generalize this to `x[a] <- TRUE`

Answer (score 4):

Another option using `tabulate`

```
n <- 6
a <- c(1, 4)
as.logical(tabulate(a, n))
# [1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```